# Solvability of the word problem in different generating sets?

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ and two generating sets $S,S'$, why is the solvability of the word problem (i.e. the ability to algorithmically decide if a word in the generating set is equal to the identity in the group) with respect to $S$ equivalent to the solvability of the word problem with respect to $S'$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming $S$ and $S'$ are finite generating sets.  Each member of $S'$ has an expression as a word in the members of $S$ and their inverses.  Thus given a word $w'$ in the members of $S'$ and their inverses, by substituting these expressions it can be expressed as a word $w$ in the members of $S$ and their inverses.  If you can solve the word problem for $S$, you can decide whether $w$ is the identity, and thus whether $w'$ is the identity.